# How to assign custom CSS to Sharepoint site

Tags: css, sharepoint

I have the Sharepoint site collection. I have my custom CSS. I want to assign the this CSS to my Sharepoint site collection . What I have to do. I don't want to use the Sharepoint designer. In fact is is restrict to use me the same. please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have deployed custom CSS is to package it as a theme in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\THEMES".

The easiest solution is to copy a theme folder, rename it, change images, css as you please and the .inf and .xml files to reflect folder name and theme name.

After the theme is done, change theme for desired sites.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do in SharePoint designer, you can do by manually editing the files (it's just much more, well, manual). the files can be accessed using WebDAV via \servername...

If you have a sandbox environment or site to play with, I suggest you make the change in SP designer and then look at the files to see what changed.